# get function is not working and it says Get http://localhost:3001/Users/%20undefined 404

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect}from 'react'
import {Link,useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'


const View=() => {
  const[user,setUser]=useState({
    name:"",
    email:"",
    phone:""
  });

  let { id } = useParams ();

  useEffect( ()=> {
    loadUser();
  },[]);

  const loadUser =  async () =>{
    const res = await axios.get(` http://localhost:3001/Users/ ${id} `);
    setUser(res.data);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container p-5">
        <h2 className="text-secondary">View Component Page</h2>
          <h1>User id : {id}</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>{user.name}</li>
            <li>{user.email}</li>
            <li>{user.phone}</li>
          </ul>
        <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/restapi">Go Back</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default View;
```

Comment: Because `id` is `undefined` . It does not work because you need to remove your whitespaces inside your uri `axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/Users/${id}`)`

Comment: even though it does not working

Comment: id is taken in useParams